# MinGW w64 with -municode asks for adding 'W' to the end of function name

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, unicode, mingw-w64

I'm building a cross-platform application using Qt. Developed on Linux but want to build on Windows, using MinGW-w64. But this compile error happened:

For example, I have a function named `func`. If adopt the default compile option `-municode` provided by `qmake`, `gcc` says `undefined reference to funcW`. If manually remove this option, `gcc` says `undefined reference to funcA`.

This error only happened for one function, others are fine. That's weird to me though.

Code can be successfully built and compiled on Linux.

Any idea how it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Many Windows functions are macros that expand to `FuncA` or `FuncW` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. `Func` is just a macro.

Comment: @chris So I just wrap the function declaration with a `#ifdef UNICODE`?

Comment: If I'm understanding right and `func` is your function, I don't know why it's being transformed. Definitely not enough to give the canonical solution.

Comment: What is the actual name of the function?  What are your includes and libraries?  Is it a compile error or link error?  Sounds like a link error which means you're not linking to the proper library.  If it is a function you wrote it sounds like you have a conflict with one of the Windows API functions with the same name.  Your options are to change your name or undef the macro that's changing the name either directly or by excluding the part ofthe windows headers that defines it and the macro.

Comment: @chris Yes, your understanding is correct. Weird thing is only one function has this issue. Others are fine to be compiled. My current walk-around is using `#ifdef UNICODE #define func funcW #else #define func funcA #endif`, which solves the problem temporarily.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah, you are right. My function name is `LoadImage` which I think is conflict with one Windows API name. After changing it, everything is fine. Thanks a lot!